# Including JS files to Crossrider project

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, crossrider

I'm working on Crossrider extension, I'm new in extension development. I've create basic project based on demos and even included Jasmine for testing.
Unfortunately I stucked on creating own resources.

Here's my debug project's structure:

```
resources\
    lib\
    spec\
        test-runner.js
    src\
        js\
            App.js
        popup.html
    background.js
    extension.js
```

test-runner.js:

```
(function() {
    appAPI.resources.includeCSS('lib/jasmine/jasmine.css');
    appAPI.resources.includeJS('lib/jasmine/jasmine.js');
    appAPI.resources.includeJS('lib/jasmine/jasmine-html.js');
    appAPI.resources.includeJS('lib/jasmine/boot.js');

    $('body').html('');

    appAPI.resources.includeJS('spec/App-spec.js');
})();
```

And here it is how I include this file:

```
appAPI.resources.includeJS('spec/test-runner.js');
```

And everything works fine.

Problems start when I'm trying to include App.js. I read that it should be done like this:

```
 appAPI.resources.addInlineJS('src/js/App.js');
```

But it's not working.

Here's my App.js:

```
var App = {
    init: function() {
        console.log('App initialized');
    }
};

$(document).ready(App.init);
```

Is it possible to include resources files inside **extension.js** or **background.js**, and also how to add more js files to project resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you are trying to achieve correctly (i.e. add a resource script to the extension code), I think you have a [scope](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/guide/scopes) issue.

[appAPI.resources.addInlineJS](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.resources-method-addInlineJS) adds the resource script to the **HTML Page** scope and once added, the code is not accessible by the **Extension Page** scope. To add the resource script to your extension code (i.e. *extension.js* code), use [appAPI.resources.includeJS](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.resources-method-includeJS) as follows:

```
appAPI.resources.includeJS('src/js/App.js');
```

[**Disclosure:** I am a Crossrider employee]